# Unmarshalling single element of XML document with JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm very new to JAXB. I have an XML doc which contains serialized object inside one of its element:

```
<?xml>
 <structure>
   ...blah-blah
   <serializedElement>
     ... JAXB xml block
   </serializedElement>
  </structure>
</xml>
```

How do I unmarshal such element?

I wrote the following:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(new StringInputStream(rawXml));
org.w3c.dom.Element obj = (org.w3c.dom.Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("serializedElement").item(0);
JAXBElement<MyJaxBObject> je = um.unmarshal(obj, MyJaxBObject.class);
System.out.println(je.getValue());
```

but this always return empty value object (although of correct class).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyJaxBObject je = javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(serializedElementAsString, MyJaxBObject.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I'm lost now - why it doesn't work whne you create unmarshaller as in my example?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is when I call unmarshall(Element, class). When I call unmarshall(Source, class) all is fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: So far I see, there is no method `unmarshall(Element, class)` in JAXB API. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Answer (score 5):

Ok, finally. The problem was in missing

```
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

After adding this line everything works fine.